# Is there a discrete Schrödinger operator with empty spectrum?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, schrodinger-operators, tridiagonal-matrices

A relatively well-known example of (continuous) Schrödinger operator with empty spectrum is the complex Airy operator on the line, i.e., the operator acting on $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ given by the differential expression
$$
  -\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}+i x,
$$
where $i$ is the imaginary unit; see for example Sec. 3.1 in this [paper](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/16M1067408?journalCode=sjmaah).

The question is whether there is a discrete counterpart of this phenomenon. More precisely, I would like to know an example (if any) of the operator $T_{v}:Dom\,T_{v}\subset\ell^{2}(\mathbb{Z})\to\ell^{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ with the maximal domain $Dom\,T_{v}=\{u\in\ell^{2}(\mathbb{Z}) \mid T_{v}u\in\ell^{2}(\mathbb{Z})\}$ and acting as
$$
 (T_{v}u)_{n}:=u_{n-1}+v_{n}u_{n}+u_{n+1}, \quad n\in\mathbb{Z},
$$
where $v=\{v_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\subset\mathbb{C}$, such that the spectrum of $T_{v}$ is empty. The operator $T_{v}$ is refered to as the discrete Schrödinger operator with potential sequence $v$. Of course, such an example (if any) must have $v$ an unbounded and non-real sequence.

**Remark:** The discrete analogue of the complex Airy operator is the discrete Schrödinger operator $T_{v}$ with $v_{n}= in$. This is not an operator with empty spectrum. Actually, the spectrum of this operator can be computed fully explicitly and equals $i\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: The discrete Schrödinger operator is a bounded perturbation of the multiplication operator $(u_n) \mapsto (v_n u_n)$. I never did perturbation theory, but I think in this case there are some continuity results for the spectrum which should imply that the spectrum is non-empty. Have you checked available results for bounded perturbations of normal operators?

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki  I haven't checked that. Thanks for pointing this out!